# Excel VBA code to determine max value in a range of strings

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write an Excel VBA script.  I have a range in a column (A2:A1000) with strings.  Every string in the range is 2 letters followed by a number (for example "AB12345" or "CD67890").
I want to search the range for every string starting with "AB", and then determine what is the max numeric value after the 2 letters.
Can someone tell me how I should go about doing this?

Comment: Show some code please or evidence or research or at least your best guess on how to do this.

Comment: Loop through your range, test for the first 2 characters, if "AB" then store value to max variable and max range. Next iteration if value is higher than stored value replace max and range. Just something to go with to start.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Not tested though.

```
MaxValue = 0
For i=2 To 1000
    If Cells(1, i).Value Like "AB*" Then
         MaxValue = Application.Max(MaxValue, CInt(Split(Cells(1, i).Value, "AB")[1]))
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: How long would it take you to test that?

Comment: Don't have Excel at the moment. This code should work except for some possible syntax mistypes. It's up to you to test that.

Answer (score 0):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF( LEFT(A2,2)<>"AB","",--RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2))
```

and copy down.  Then in another cell enter:

```
=MAX(B2:B1000)
```

[image]

This approach avoids the use of an array formula.